# Reference for specific values of incomplete elliptic integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, special-functions, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

In  Wolfram's website specific values of *incomplete* elliptic integral of first, second and third kind are given in terms of *complete* elliptic integrals of first, second and third kind.

For the incomplete integral of first kind [$\text{F}(z, m)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticF/03/01/02/), the site lists the following relations:

$$
\text{F}(\pi/2, m)= \text{K}(m)\\
\text{F}(\text{csc}^{-1}(\sqrt{m}), m)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\text{K}\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)
$$

Similarly for incomplete elliptic integral of second kind [$\text{E}(z,m)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticE2/03/01/02/):

$$
\text{E}(\pi/2, m)= \text{E}(m)\\
\text{E}(\text{csc}^{-1}(\sqrt{m}), m)= \sqrt{m} \left( \text{E}\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)+ \left(\frac{1}{m}-1\right)\text{K}\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)\right)
$$

and for the third kind [$\Pi(n,\, z,\,m)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticPi3/03/01/02/):

$$
\Pi(n,\,\pi/2,\, m)=\Pi(n,\,m)\\
\Pi(n,\, \text{csc}^{-1}(\sqrt{m}),\,m)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\Pi\left(\frac{n}{m},\,\frac{1}{m}\right)
$$

I would like to use this identities in a calculation however the site does not list references. I would appreciate a comprehensive reference list for these relations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a few references listed [on this page about the first kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html), similarly for the [second](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html) and [third](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheThirdKind.html) kinds. But you'll have to do some digging from there....

Answer (score 0):

A good list of relations involving elliptic integrals is to be found in the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19). Your examples are obtained by applying the [reciprocal modulus/parameter transformation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7#E4) with the amplitude $\phi=\frac\pi2$, which makes the integral(s) on one side complete.